How can I add the latest Sergei Strelec iso as a boot option in Grub?
I have a dual boot UEFI system with Windows 11 on one SSD and Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS on another.  I use the grub menu to select which OS to boot.  I've studied several web postings describing the steps for adding a bootable iso to the grub menu.  They all involve launching Linux distros by adding commands to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file.  Here's one such posting:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/boot-from-iso-files-using-grub2-boot-loader
I'm trying to figure out how to adapt the procedure to the 2024 Sergei Strelec WinPE utility iso.  The iso currently resides in my "Home" folder.  I don't know the proper lines to add to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom to pull this off.  In fact, my Ubuntu does not even have the 40_custom file to edit.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I'm a linux beginner.  Thanks.
Here's the iso I'm trying to launch:
https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sergei_strelecs_winpe.html
...an extremely useful tool.

This question is similar to: 20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A custom file won't exist until its created; as its not a standard file, but a file that users can add their custom entries they want displayed.  Please also be precise with details; you mention Ubuntu 24 which doesn't exist; maybe you're using Ubuntu Core 24 being closest in name, which is the snap only version of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server, but its best if you're specific.  Knowing what you're using allows more specific responses, as software versions change over time.

This iso is a Windows 11, 10, and 8 PE bootable disk for computer, hard drive and partition maintenance, disk and partition backup and restoration, computer diagnostics, data recovery, and Windows installation, and it should be used to boot the PC from a CD/DVD or USB drive not from a hard drive.

"This question is similar to: 20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu..." The discussion deals with a Linux distro iso.  It does not provide the specifics needed for the Strelec iso.  I'm pretty sure the kernel info will be different.
"...it should be used to boot the PC from a CD/DVD or USB drive not from a hard drive..."  I'm aware of the conventional use of the tool.  But I want to make it a permanent part of my UEFI workstation.  If I can pull this off, it will be CONVENIENT and very COOL.

This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside the question! There is a button below so that you can Answer Your Own Question. If you think someone else has already answered your question. You can accept that answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Since the application information says that it is a Windows ISO
You can try to boot the contents of the ISO as if it were Windows.
To do this you need to:
Create an NTFS partition and extract all the contents of the ISO to it.
Then create or modify the file /etc/grub.d/40_custom, from the Ubuntu installation that installed Grub.
In this file you must add:
We assume that the original operating systems are in a GPT partition with UEFI boot
menuentry "Sergei Strelec WinPE " {
set root=(hd0,6)
insmod part_gpt
insmod ntfs
insmod chain
chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}

In set root=(hd0,6) you must correctly indicate the disk hd0 or hd1 and the correct partition number where the iso was unzipped.
Once the file has been saved, you must run
sudo update-grub

So that the change is made in the Grub menu

I'll try this when I get a chance.  Have you tested this...or is it just a guess?

I haven't used Windows since 2001 and I don't plan on using it. This is the procedure to boot a Windows iso. Since the iso mentioned claims to be a Windows iso it should work.

Okay, here's where I am.  With the contents of the ISO copied to an NTFS partition, my motherboard bios recognizes the "UEFI OS", and can launch it.  However, when attempting to add it to the grub menu, I get these error messages:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/vimix/theme.txt
/etc/grub.d/40_custom: 3: menuentry: not found
/etc/grub.d/40_custom: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Feels like we're very close.  I don't know what's wrong with the syntax.  It looks correct to me.

There was no 40_custom file, so I created it with the first line being #!/bin/sh .  I don't know if anything else is required.  I manually typed the commands you posted, changing the drive/partition to hd0,gpt4.  No joy.

My latest attempt using: '
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
hope this works...
hope this works...
hope this works...
menuentry "Sergei Strelec WinPE " {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt4'
chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}'
I no longer have syntax errors.  But when I try to boot the selection it says hd0 gpt4 could not be found.  It doesn't make sense.

set root=(hd0,4)

How To Add Grub Entries Ubuntu 24.04
In Ubuntu 24.04, Grub2 is the default bootloader.To add custom entries, you’ll need to modify the /etc/default/grub file and the scripts in the /etc/grub.d/ directory. Here’s a step-by-step guide:
Backup important files:Before making changes, backup /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files using sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/grub.d/* /path/to/backup/directory.
Edit /etc/default/grub: Open the file with a text editor (e.g., sudo nano /etc/default/grub) and add the following lines at the end:

GRUB_CUSTOM_MENUENTRY="Your Custom Menu Entry"
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"  # Set the default entry to the new custom one


Replace “Your Custom Menu Entry” with the desired name and description for your custom entry.
Create a new script in /etc/grub.d/: Create a new file (e.g., sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom) and add the following contents:

#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Your Custom Menu Entry" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
}


Replace the kernel and initrd versions with the ones you want to use.
Adjust the set root line to match your partition layout.
Make the script executable: Run sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom to make the script executable.
Update Grub configuration: Run sudo update-grub to rebuild the Grub configuration file (/boot/grub/grub.cfg).
Verify the custom entry: Reboot your system and check the Grub menu to ensure your custom entry is present and functional.
Remember to be cautious when editing system files, and make sure to backup important files before making changes. If you encounter issues, you can restore the original files from your backup directory.

This looks like another very generic and generalized answer.  I had hoped that someone would actually test with the specific iso that I've mentioned to work out the specific entries.

Sure the question had Ubuntu 24, I don't know what version that is, so I added an answer regarding 24.04.01 LTS the most current version.  I have built several ISOs using this method. I have installed Ubuntu 14 in the same fashion. I thought the object was to learn? However this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1536795/371200 does give you more clues to the correct format of the GRUB menu entry.

Sorry.  I've already seen the information you provided in several places on the web.  The specific iso I'm trying to boot is the Sergei Strelec WinPE utility disk...which I provided a link to.  I'm not trying to boot a linux distro iso.
